# InAppMessaging.AWSPinpointProvider - Failed to initialize AWSPinpoint', [Error: Native module not found]

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, push-notification, aws-amplify

I have recently updated my react native app which was using @aws-amplify/pushnotification (deprecated) to use @aws-amplify/rtn-push-notification. This involved following the migration process here: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/push-notifications/migrate-from-previous-version/q/platform/react-native/.

After this update calling Analytics.updateEndpoint now results in the error:

```
InAppMessaging.AWSPinpointProvider - Failed to initialize AWSPinpoint', [Error: Native module not found]
```

I really don't get why InAppMessaging is being referenced in the error as this has not been installed by me and is not relevant to push notifications.

Here is the code trying to run this request:

```
import {Analytics} from 'aws-amplify';

const handleToken = async () => {
  const { attributes: {sub} } = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('pushNotificationToken');

  if (sub && token) {
    Analytics.updateEndpoint({
      address: token,
      optOut: "NONE",
      userId: sub,
      channelType: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "APNS" : "GCM",
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log('created', response);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error updating endpoint', error);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the package.json with all the packages and versions:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/rtn-push-notification": "^1.1.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.5",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.12",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.23.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel-v4": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.10.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.5",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.207.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

Comment: is this issue fixed for you?, I am having this kind of issue, needed help.